# Python give me a Value error too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I have a problem with an error and I can not handle it. I want to download music from youtube and automatically extract descriptions to capitols on youtube. I do not know why I scraped a Web and Stakowerflow too but I can solute it
The expectation is a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Lukas/OneDrive - ZSMosBB/Dokumenty/python_scripts/AMP/main.py", line 628, in <module>
    music_time,first_links_to_description = youtube_single_download(tag,number2)
  File "c:/Users/Lukas/OneDrive - ZSMosBB/Dokumenty/python_scripts/AMP/main.py", line 203, in youtube_single_download
    old_mins,old_seconds = convert(music_time)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

and here is my convert function to convert second into minutes:

```
def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600

    mins = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60

    return hours, mins, seconds
```

Comment: "convert" returns a sequence with more than two items. A better answer needs more information.

Comment: You might want to show your *convert()* function code

Comment: Thank you for showing your *convert()* function. Had you noticed that it returns a 3-tuple whereas you're only unpacking 2 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convert() function returns a 3-tuple but the calling code only wants 2 values. If the *hours* value is not wanted then:

```
_, mins, seconds = convert(lenght)
```

**Note:**

No attempt made to correct OP's spelling error